Program for Microsoft Windows 10 that can surface test only selected sectors
I did a surface test with dark green Hard Disk Sentinel Pro 6.20 and I suspect the disk got disconnected near the end, which made Hard Disk Sentinel Pro consider them to be bad sectors. The test lasted 23h20min so I would prefer to not rerun it.


Therefore I'm looking for a program for Microsoft Windows 10 that can do a surface test for only some sectors I select.

Okay Franck, I'll bite.  What makes Hard Disk Sentinel Pro dark green?  Is it moldy?  Is it experiencing anger and turning into The Hulk?  What's going on?

@EndAntisemiticHate sectors with slower read :)

Ah, that's less entertaining, but makes more sense. ;)   BTW, what capacity and type of drive is this (HDD/SSD), and how is it connected?  I'm assuming it's an HDD, but want to make sure.

@EndAntisemiticHate Seagate Exos X22 20TB SATA 6Gb/s 7200RPM 3.5-inch Enterprise HDD (ST20000NM004E) connected via SABRENT USB 3.0 to SATA External Hard Drive Lay-Flat Docking Station.

Turns out Hard Disk Sentinel  Pro (non-free, Windows 10) has this option to run a surface test only selected sectors:


Official site: https://www.hdsentinel.com/

Thanks for the self-answer Franck.  Can you add a link when you get a chance?  Also, the option to which you refer is the checkbox "Limit testing to specific data blocks", correct?

@EndAntisemiticHate link added, correct it's the checkbox "Limit testing to specific data blocks"
